# Make current tab active after postback bootstrap tabs

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap tabs in my asp.net project, Tabs are working fine but when the user clicks on any of the button or any postback occurs,

First tab get selected.

I tried hidden field with jquery but it's not working.

What am I missing kindly elaborate please.

Here is my code :

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
              $(document).ready(function () {
                  var selectedTab = $("#<%=hfTab.ClientID%>");
                  var tabId = selectedTab.val() != "" ? selectedTab.val() : "personal";
                 $('#dvTab a[href="#' + tabId + '"]').tab('show');
                 $("#dvTab a").click(function () {
                     selectedTab.val($(this).attr("href").substring(1));
                 });
             });
        </script>
                                        <div id="dvTab">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="active"><a href="#personal" aria-controls="personal" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Personal Information</a></li>
    <li><a href="#pf" aria-controls="pf" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">PF Nominee</a></li>
    <li><a href="#gf" aria-controls="gf" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">GF Nominee</a></li>
    <li><a href="#edu" aria-controls="edu" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Education Details</a></li>
    <li><a href="#fam" aria-controls="fam" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Family Details</a></li>
    <li><a href="#emphist" aria-controls="emphist" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Employment History</a></li>                      
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="personal" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active">                                       
         ...                                          
    </div>
    <div id="pf" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane">                                           
        ..
    </div>
    <div id="gf" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane">
      ..
    </div>
    <div id="edu" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane">
      <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn_AddEdu" Text="Add Degree/Certificate" OnClick="btn_AddEdu_Click" /><br />    
    </div>
</div>                                                                       
</div>                               
      <asp:HiddenField ID="hfTab" runat="server" />
```

The button is placed in Education Details Tab,
On the click event of that button , I added :

```
protected void btn_AddEdu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 hfTab.Value = "edu";
}
```

Comment: remove `active` class from your first `<li>` and use `active` class on `<li>` dynamically for open particular tab.

Comment: how can i use it dynamically

Comment: you can use `id` on your `<li>` like `<li id='personal'>` 
and check your hidden field like below.
like this : `var selectedTab = $("#<%=hfTab.ClientID%>");
var tabId = selectedTab.val() != "" ? selectedTab.val() : "personal";
 $("#"+tabId ).addClass('active');`

Hope it helps you

Comment: Could you post the html for the entire page?I tried re-creating your problem on my side but it's working 100%.So I want to see the entire page and code behind

Comment: @DenisWessels have a look http://jsbin.com/supokoyoho/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the script references in this order(**at the top of the page**):

1. Bootstrap CSS first
2. jQuery
3. bootstrap.js

**Refrences:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**Complete solution:**

Copy and paste this code as is and it will work:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var selectedTab = $("#<%=hfTab.ClientID%>");
            var tabId = selectedTab.val() != "" ? selectedTab.val() : "personal";
            $('#dvTab a[href="#' + tabId + '"]').tab('show');
            $("#dvTab a").click(function () {
                selectedTab.val($(this).attr("href").substring(1));
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <div id="dvTab">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li class="active"><a href="#personal" aria-controls="personal" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Personal Information</a></li>
                <li><a href="#pf" aria-controls="pf" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">PF Nominee</a></li>
                <li><a href="#gf" aria-controls="gf" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">GF Nominee</a></li>
                <li><a href="#edu" aria-controls="edu" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Education Details</a></li>
                <li><a href="#fam" aria-controls="fam" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Family Details</a></li>
                <li><a href="#emphist" aria-controls="emphist" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Employment History</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="personal" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active">
                    ...                                          
                </div>
                <div id="pf" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane">
                    ..
                </div>
                <div id="gf" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane">
                    ..
                    G Nom NOm
                </div>
                <div id="edu" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane">
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn_AddEdu" Text="Add Degree/Certificate" OnClick="btn_AddEdu_Click" /><br />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
         <asp:HiddenField ID="hfTab" runat="server" />   
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Add the scripts in the <head> section.Look at the example I've posted.Do it exactly like that

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
$('#dvTab a[href="#' + tabId + '"]').tab('show');
```

to

```
$('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + tabId + '"]').tab('show');
```

You are selecting on basis of `id` `dvTab` which is not there.

**Edit**

As per your comments your jquery file is not added properly please add jquery and bootstrap in order. Also include these file at bottom of page.

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script> 
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: @AlinaAnjum Are you storing value of each tab in a separate button_click event ?

Comment: problem is not different buttons, right now i just added one button in the mentioned tab and tab is losing its current state after postback

Comment: @AlinaAnjum i think your issue is your javascript code is not working because i copied same example and it was not working as i was getting error `.tabs()` is not a function. Please check the browser console if there is any error ?

Comment: Kindly suggest me the possible solution if there is any error in the current code

Comment: Have you checked the browser console ?

Comment: So please move javascript files like bootstrap and other jquery files at end of page.

Comment: Have you seen it  jsbin.com/supokoyoho/edit?html,js,output

Comment: You have not change this line
`$('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + tabId + '"]').tab('show');`

Comment: His problem is not showing the tabs.The tabs are showing fine.The problem is whena postback happens the tab is reset to the first one

Comment: Yeah i know tabs are showing but bootstrap function is not applying properly.

Comment: MyProfile.aspx:1254 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Oh come on this simply means your jquery file not added properly. Have you included the jquery file ? If yes move it to end of documnet but before bootstrap files.

Comment: This is how your files should be. These are mine files just for example

Comment: `<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>`
`<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>`
`<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   `

Comment: <!-- Javascript -->
        <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/wow.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/retina-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/waypoints.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/scripts.js"></script>
    </div>
    </form>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112992/discussion-between-mairaj-ahmad-and-alina-anjum).

Comment: please drag drop file from solution explorer on page and it will automatically add it with correct path.

Comment: I gave Vote for your support dear

Comment: @AlinaAnjum Thanks .